# Libgdx on android not able to detect GDX fonts

Tags: android, fonts, intellij-idea, libgdx

I am trying to render simple text using the libgdx `BitmapFont`:

```
 font = new BitmapFont();
 font.draw(batch, "Tap anywhere to begin!", 100, 100);
```

It works fine in the desktop,But android it gives this error:

```
07-30 08:12:35.518: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(817): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 82
        com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: com/badlogic/gdx/utils/arial-15.fnt (Classpath)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:132)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:77)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont$BitmapFontData.<init>(BitmapFont.java:715)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont.<init>(BitmapFont.java:114)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont.<init>(BitmapFont.java:73)
        at com.mangokidzee.amphibian.Activity1.create(Activity1.java:23)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:322)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1505)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Seems it is unable to load the font file

```
File not found: com/badlogic/gdx/utils/arial-15.fnt (Classpath)
```

I am using `intelliJ Idea` not the Eclipse IDE. I think this is due to some path configuration issue but not able to figure out what. Can someone help me out?

**Update**

I have opened sample libgdx demo apk created using `eclipse`, it has these **4** files in the gdx `utils` folder

- arial-15.fnt
- arial-15.png
- JsonReader.rl
- XmlReader.rl

whereas in my apk generated using `intelliJ`, it has only 2 files

- JsonReader.rl
- XmlReader.rl

`arial-15` is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removing the `gdx-sources.jar` from main `libs` dir, works fine but we need the documentation when we press Ctrl+Q when using IntelliJ.

So, I didn't delete the `gdx-sources.jar` but I **MOVED** it in a new directory under `Main`, named it `sourcelibs` and then I went to `project structure/Libraries/Mainlibs` (or whatever) and at the dependencies I deleted the sources entry (it had no meaning any more) and pressed the "plus sign" to attach files or directories and I added the new directory. Now there is a new sources entry with the new directory.

So now there is no error (thanks to user2206917), and we also have the documentation!

Answer (score 5):

After I removed the gdx-sources.jar from main lib dir,every thing works fine.
Maybe a bug of IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: It worked for me too. I was running the Pax Britannica demo on IntelliJ

Answer (score 2):

Link the assets between Android module and Main module:

Create a directory named data in the main module, and make a sym-link from the assets directory in the Android module.

Here's the [reference](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/IntelliJIDEALibgdx).

Comment: Thanks @Sajal,t missed that one. :)

Answer (score -1):

I got this error because of a problem with the desktop run configuration.  As noted on [the libgdx docs](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Using-libgdx-with-intellij-idea#alternative-2-working-directory) (Alternative 2: Working directory) the working directory of the build configuration should be set to the android/assets folder.